ros2 controller does not work
I have written the following launch file for the controller of my robot:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    simple_controller = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "simple_velocity_controller",
            "--controller-manager",
            "/controller_manager"
        ]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,      
        simple_controller
    ])

If I want to start I get the console shows the following answer:
samy@Samy:~/bumperbot_ws$ ros2 launch bumperbot_controller controller.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/samy/.ros/log/2024-10-19-23-23-45-880863-Samy-4843
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [spawner-1]: process started with pid [4844]
[INFO] [spawner-2]: process started with pid [4846]
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1729373027.707296649] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-2] [INFO] [1729373027.793097378] [spawner_simple_velocity_controller]: Loaded simple_velocity_controller
[spawner-1] [ERROR] [1729373032.767408382] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-1]: process has died [pid 4844, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
[spawner-2] [ERROR] [1729373037.784583481] [spawner_simple_velocity_controller]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-2]: process has died [pid 4846, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner simple_velocity_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
samy@Samy:~/bumperbot_ws$ 

What have I to change? Is it possible that the mistake is in an oter file?

please also add the console output where you launched gazebo (with gazebo_ros2_control)

As such joint_state_broadcaster_spawner doesn't need controller_manager information. refer to the ros2_control_demo_examples for more information.

I haven't asked for the configuration but for the console output of the gazebo plugin. The spawners reach the service but Failed to activate controller, and there should be any output of the controller_manager why it failed.
